# Why is it necessary to explicitly specify the foreign keys when joining tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate

SQL server is aware of table dependencies based on foreign keys, so why is it necessary to explicitly specify a `JOIN ON` foreign keys?

Real world working example (This query works):

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN roles ON users.role_id=roles.id
```

Implicit example (This query doesn't work):

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN roles
```

Shouldn't SQL implicitly and correctly assume that if no `ON` keyword is specified joining should be done on the foreign keys?

I understand that the benefit of this may be trivial, but after leveraging this feature in SQL APIs such as Java Hibernate's query language I can't see why this wouldn't be built in to SQL.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers so far. Although they are interesting, none of them answer the original question regarding SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

SQL *does* sort-of support this notion.  The standard includes `natural join`, which SQL Server has **happily** not implemented.  This allows you to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u NATURAL JOIN
     roles r;
```

A `natural join` has no `on` clause.

Alas, it does something slightly different from what you suggest.  Instead of using foreign keys, it simply uses columns with the same name.  I consider this an abomination, because SQL does have explicit foreign key declarations and this would be the right place to use them.

Comment: Wow... didn't know SQL Server didn't implement natural joins, since I don't use them myself, I would consider this a **feature** of SQL Server.

Comment: Postgres supports the `USING (col1, col2, col3,..)` syntax, which makes the join column names explicit, though it requires that the names be identical in the two tables.  It's a little less wordy than writing out the complete equi-join syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite normal for tables to have multiple foreign key relationships between them.

In this case, what would you expect the database to do when there are two FKs between two tables. Pick one at random?

Typical example:

- A table `CLIENT`.
- A table `PURCHASE`. Since a purchase happens between two clients it needs two FKs to `CLIENT`: **seller_id**, and **buyer_id**, both pointing to `CLIENT`.

Comment: Interesting.  In such a case, perhaps you could specify the name of the foreign key constraint to use.  That would be optional if the conditions were unambiguous.

Comment: Note, though, that SQL Server does not allow creation of foreign keys that result in multiple pathways between two tables, because it can't do cascading updates and deletions under those circumstances.  To get that functionality you need to use Postgres, SQLite, or Firebird.

Comment: @rd_nielsen Can you elaborate on the "mutiple pathways"? I've been testing in SQL Server and it seems it allows quite a few foreign key options. See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a5467b/2

Comment: @TheImpaler - Multiple pathways can't be created when updates or deletions are cascaded.  Try adding `on update cascade on delete cascade` to the foreign key declarations in your SQL Fiddle.  This is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186973(v=sql.105); see the "Multiple Cascading Actions" section.  The documentation is from 2012, but still applies.  Also see https://splinterofthesingularity.blogspot.com/2011/04/converging-and-cyclic-cascades-in.html for more detail

Comment: @rd_nielsen Thanks, duly noted.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff , SQL Server has no qualms notifying the user when a query is ambiguous, so I don't see a reason why it couldn't do the same when it can't safely assume keys to join on.

Answer (score 1):

Every time there are implicit operations happening it makes it more difficult to do exactly what you want. Having a natural join seems fast at first but if you have to debug it then you will have to go figure out exactly how the join worked. Was it using foreign keys?  Was it just columns with the same name? I'm using NHIBERNATE right now and it seems everyone in my team has a much harder time with it to do exactly what is needed.